# Append `.php` extension to URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm not familiar at all with the process behind this, but what I would like is to have a rule in the `.htaccess` file that will append `.php` after a URL ***IFF*** the URL is indeed a file.

I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

for the redirecting if a user types in the URL without the `.php` extension, but in addition to the redirect, I would like to actually append the URL with the `.php` extension.  Is this possible?

Comment: mod_rewrite *rewrites*. Redirection only happens in specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `R` flag so that the client is instructed to redirect to the new URL.